# Standalone ActiveMQ client on GlassFish

Tags: java, activemq-classic, glassfish-3

Hello guys i have such issue i make all thing like [tutorial](http://javadude.wordpress.com/2011/07/21/glassfish-v3-1-running-embedded-activemq-for-jms-part-1/) says. So now i want to lookup my Topics and connection factories that i configured but it do not see them. i make something like :

> ```
>   try {
>         Properties propertiesAMQ = new Properties();
>         propertiesAMQ.load(new FileInputStream("AMQ.properties"));
>         logger.info("Property file loaded succesfully...");
>         propertiesAMQ.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
>             "org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
>         propertiesAMQ.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL,
>                 "tcp://localhost:61616");
>     Context ctx = new InitialContext(propertiesAMQ);
>         javax.jms.TopicConnectionFactory factory = (javax.jms.TopicConnectionFactory) ctx
>                 .lookup("amqpool");
> javax.jms.Topic mytopic = (javax.jms.Topic) ctx.lookup("amqmsg")
> ```
>
> }

And recieve NameNotFoundException. If i use name of connection factory such as "ConnectionFactory" it will be ok but then it will not see my Topic What i did wrong? Have u other examples of this subject? I'm using glassfish 3.0.1 and AMQ 5.5.0

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are missing the namespace, you can look the exact name in the glassfish console, but most probably it should be;

```
javax.jms.Topic mytopic = (javax.jms.Topic) ctx.lookup("java:amqmsg")
```

Comment: Ok now it's - Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: scheme java not recognized.
Ok it work if i writelike this:
ConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
factory.createConnection();
ActiveMQQueue mytopic = (ActiveMQQueue) ctx.lookup("dynamicQueues/amqmsg");
But what factory it use i do not know

Answer (score 0):

How do you create your Topic resource? I had a similar problem and the solution was to create the Admin Resource Object using Glassfish command-line tool 'asadmin'. Creating it using the Glassfish admin console did not work (causing NameNotFoundException).

I ended up creating my Queu resource with the following command: 'create-admin-object –restype javax.jms.Queue –raname activemq-rar-5.7.0 –property PhysicalName=queueName queueName'